# Deselect CheckboxAll when one of checkboxes is uncheck android

Tags: android, xml, checkbox

In my Application, i tried to create a Array with multiple check boxes.My app worked when i click CheckBoxAll select all checkboxes and when i uncheck CheckBoxAll deselect all chekboxes.But, if i deselect one of the chekboxes when all of them are checked,CheckBoxAll its not un-checking..

This is my array

```
 ArrayList<CheckBox> boxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();

checkBoxAll = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBoxAll);
        boxes.add(checkBoxAll);
        checkBoxCompany = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBoxCompany);
        boxes.add(checkBoxCompany);
        checkBoxType = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBoxType);
        boxes.add(checkBoxType);
        checkBoxName = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBoxName);
        boxes.add(checkBoxName);
        checkBoxPhone = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBoxPhone);
        boxes.add(checkBoxPhone);
        checkBoxAddress = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBoxAddress);
        boxes.add(checkBoxAddress);
        checkBoxEmail = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBoxEmail);
        boxes.add(checkBoxEmail);
        checkBoxwebSite = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBox4WebSite);
        boxes.add(checkBoxwebSite);
```

and this is my function

```
 public void checkAllListener() {
        checkBoxAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                for(CheckBox chk : boxes) {
                    chk.setChecked(isChecked);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the logic to detect when a checkbox its clicked and uncheck the checkBoxAll. You will need a listener to handle the checked of any of your checkboxes.

```
public class checks extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener{
    private ArrayList<CheckBox> boxes;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        boxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();

        checkBoxAll = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBoxAll);
        boxes.add(checkBoxAll);
        checkBoxCompany = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBoxCompany);
        boxes.add(checkBoxCompany);
        checkBoxType = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBoxType);
        boxes.add(checkBoxType);
        checkBoxName = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBoxName);
        boxes.add(checkBoxName);
        checkBoxPhone = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBoxPhone);
        boxes.add(checkBoxPhone);
        checkBoxAddress = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBoxAddress);
        boxes.add(checkBoxAddress);
        checkBoxEmail = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBoxEmail);
        boxes.add(checkBoxEmail);
        checkBoxwebSite = createCheckBox(R.id.checkBox4WebSite);
        boxes.add(checkBoxwebSite);   

        for(CheckBox check : boxes){
            check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this); 
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        switch (buttonView.getId()) {
        case R.id.checkBoxAll:
            for(CheckBox chk : boxes) {
                chk.setChecked(isChecked);
            }
            break;

        default:
            boxes.get(0).setChecked(false);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```